# jQuery: calculate the top in live jquery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

http://jsfiddle.net/xHE3S/

There are 12 li. Each row contains 3 li. So there will be four rows.

What I am doing is first calculating the each li location from ul and then using ajax fetching the product data. Ajax data displaying  in new row below the clicked li.

To display the new li created through ajax i am applying top . now the problem starts here.

For first row it displaying correctly just below the row1

Now when i click on row 2 product it will calculate the distance again and apply the top to newly created li. While previously created element removed when user clicks on anyother  li. So in distance calculation it also calculate the space covered by new created li. So the second row li will display on row3 li because getting wrong **top**

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.products li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('li.new-rows').remove();
        var relativeY = jQuery(this).offset().top - jQuery('ul.products').offset().top;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: links,
            beforeSend: function () {
                alert('Yes');
            },
            success: function (data) {

                var dd = jQuery(data).find('#content .product').html();
                if (jQuery('.products li.new-rows').length == 0) {
                    jQuery('.products').append('<li class="new-rows"></li>');
                    jQuery('.new-rows').html('<div class="data-len">' + dd + '</div>');
                    jQuery('.new-rows').css({
                        top: relativeY + 280
                    });
                } else {
                    jQuery('.new-rows').html(dd);
                    jQuery('.new-rows').css({
                        top: relativeY + 280
                    });
                }

            }


            )
        };)
    };)
};
```

in this screen you can see it is getting top correctly

[image: properly working . getting right top for created li] ![enter image description here]![enter image description here]

while here it is calcultes the height covered by li , which is created using ajax.
  so top value getting addition of it. you can see it is going on third row.

[image]

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle for us to be able to see what you want to do/get ? Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to add li's in a certain order? if so instead of positioning them, why not use [`.after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and then place it after the li you want (using `li.eq(index)`) instead of just appending it to the bottom of the list and moving it with css

Comment: no what i am doing is i am appending the li whenuser click on any li. the newly created li will be the last element now i want to display it in new row below the clicked element.  you can see the screenshot. for the first one it  is working correctly while when we click on second row li it consider the space cover by the created li and add that top in newly created li. so for row2 the new li top should be around 320 px while  getting 280px+320px  where 280px is the height of the previously open element. i tried to get the top in ajax but it is not working, need help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xHE3S/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<--Deleted old code-->

Is this jsfiddle what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/pn3dx/

I used Pete's suggestion of using `after`. I used `$(this)` to get the li the user clicked on:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<li class="new-rows">new</li>');
});
```

### Edit:

If you want the added `li` to have the same functionality, then use `delegate()` http://jsfiddle.net/pn3dx/3/

```
$('ul').delegate('li', 'click', function(e){
    $(this).after('<li class="new-rows">new</li>');
});
```

Comment: it won't work.. problem is when user click on row1 li> for first row1 the top would be 0 . to display the newly created li just below it fetching data using ajax. now to set the location of the newly created li in ym code you can see variable : relativeY  that calculates the height of the row1 whish is 280px. the newly creates li's position is absolute what i am doing is just passing the calculated top to new li. it looks like screenshot 1  while when i click on second row li , if we click on second row li it will consider the space covered by that li and add displaing on third row.

Comment: for example: the for row 2 top should be 500px while getting 800px; here extra 300px is space covered by the li created through ajax. check screenshot 1. that is why it is pushing it down over the third row. need help

Comment: Does this help? If not could you make a jsfiddle showing what you want?

Comment: check this out.. this is real sitution,. in my case it is appearing below the row 1 and moving the row 2 down. so that new row data appear properly. http://jsfiddle.net/pn3dx/4/

Comment: I'm still not clear on exactly what it is you're looking for. Is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/pn3dx/5/